# How do I animate URL transitions?

Tags: javascript, url, animation, transition, gsap

I am trying to create a site that animates page transitions instead of just loading the next page. I found a great example at jetlag.photos (feel free to check that out). Their animations work flawlessly on the desktop and mobile. I know they used the GreenSock library to help with this but I do not see much in the way of URL transitions in the documentation. Please help!

Comment: That greatly depends on the kind of animation you want. Some can be done with CSS, some by catching and cancelling all actions that load a new page, invoke the animation, then perform the navigation themselves, and practically all of them by dynamically loading the content or packing everything into one file in the first place, and either not modifying the URL at all, using location.hash to change the #hash at the end of an URL to separate pages, or by using window.history.pushState() to modify anything but protocol and domain. As it stands however, your question is way too broad.

Comment: You're overly broad with your question, here. Please share an example of something you've already tried, so the community can try to help you.

Comment: have you taken a look at **[this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0mbt7xV7CAE)** where **[Petr Tichy](https://ihatetomatoes.net/)** breaks down the animations part. URL transitions are still not covered but the video is a good starting point to understand the animations themselves.

Comment: Thanks Tahir Ahmed. Awesome video. Really helps out.
Siguza, thanks for the URL tips. they seems to do the basics for what I need.